# Clutch slipping on Scania 420

Tags: clutch, scania

My Scania's new clutch is slipping but there is no smell at all. Was slipping on and off. Then she's slipping and then all of a sudden she is riding smoothly, but a few days ago she was slipping a lot and had no usable power.  I had the clutch and pressure plate removed, there's absolutely nothing wrong with it. May be you can suggest what the problem could be? This is puzzling me.

Comment: All mechanisms to engage/disengage the clutch are operating as expected? Wear and/or binding of these components can cause random engagement.

Comment: Would it be fair to describe the behavior as seeming like the clutch pedal was depressed? With no power transfer, but also no smell of the clutch heating up as it slipped?

This makes me think that the problem could be in the clutch linkage with something causing the clutch to activate without pressing the pedal. A bit of poking around with the Google leads me to think that there is a clutch servo between the clutch pedal and the actual clutch. Could the servo be hanging up?

Answer (score 1):

When clutch was checked was the throw-out bearing checked and replaced?
It is usually a low cost item and best replaced at the same time as the clutch.  While inspection of that part may look acceptable and it may seem to slip back and forth on the guide it is possible that it binds under load when clutch depressed and doe not full slide back.